# HashSet in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, collections

I have two POJO classes address and user_details.
I need to know how the code runs

```
 @ElementCollection
    private Set<Address>listOfAddresses = new HashSet();
    public Set<Address> getListOfAddresses() {
        return listOfAddresses;
    }
    public void setListOfAddresses(Set<Address> listOfAddresses) {
        this.listOfAddresses = listOfAddresses;
    }
```

I had implemented in main method as

```
Address addr2 = new Address();
        addr2.setStreet("Second Street");
        addr2.setCity("Second City");
        addr2.setState("Second State");
        addr2.setPincode("20002");

user.getListOfAddresses().add(addr2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The unfortunate answer is "it depends".
HashSet will use the hashcode() function on any object you put into it. Since we don't have the code for your Address class, we can't really know how your object implements this method.

Generally though, most IDEs provide methods that allow you to automatically generate a reasonable implementation of hashcode(). Keep in mind you should also override equals(Object o) for any object you override hashcode() for.

hashcode() and equals() have what is known as a "contract". When two objects are equal, their hashcode() method should return the same number. The opposite does not need to be true.

If you implement this correctly for Address, the HashSet should simply filter out duplicate objects (as intended).